# Phoenix CodeReload not working

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

I have a phoenix application, however I have needed to restart the server manually after every backend change.  `code_reload` is enabled, and `plug CodeReload` is being used.

I've tried generating a new project (`mix phoenix.new --no-brunch`), I've tried different editors (vim, vscode, atom, and textedit), I've tried always requiring `plug CodeReload` in my endpoint, and I've tried manually setting the `MIX_ENV` to `dev` - however my project still won't compile when I change a file.  How should I go about tracking down what the problem is?

CodeReload does not work when running `mix phoenix.server` or `iex -S mix phoenix.server`

Comment: Which file are you changing?

Comment: Check your config for **live_reload** settings like here: [see ## Configuration](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_live_reload/blob/master/lib/phoenix_live_reload/live_reloader.ex). You may have to configure which file changes will trigger a live reload.

Comment: @Dogbert models, controllers, routers - really any backend files.

Comment: @guitarman live_reload is only for static assets, correct?  I'm writing an API with phoenix, the front end is in another repository.  Even so I've tried adding new directories to the `live_reload` setting, and that did not work either.

Comment: @cadlac: It's not only for static assets. I added my gettext *.po translation files for example. If you add another row in the patterns list, you need to add a regex for the files you want to watch, not only directories.

Comment: @cadlac and code reloading doesn't work for you even in a brand new project (`mix phoenix.new --no-brunch`) if you make a change in the default template or controller?

Comment: @Dogbert correct, regardless of which editor/terminal I use.  I'm on OS X 10.12.5 if that helps at all

Answer (score 8):

I was running into the same problem. In my case it was caused by a VS Code plugin (https://github.com/iampeterbanjo/vscode-elixir-linter). Disabling the plugin made the code reloading work again.

Comment: Actually it does for VS Code users.  Uninstalling `iampeterbanjo.elixirlinter` worked perfectly.

It seems to be a common problem, editor plugins interfering with code reloading.

A similar issue was also reported here, https://github.com/JakeBecker/vscode-elixir-ls/issues/24, but was fixed.

Comment: For me, it was VSCode itself. I typically leave the app open for weeks at a time, and there was apparently an update that needed a restart. Code reloading worked after restarting VSCode.

Comment: This isn't just VS Code. I use neovim and when my language server failed it caused the code reloading to stop working.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue - the server logs in dev showed a rebuild, but the rendered HTML never updated. Eventually, I realized I was missing `:elixir` from `reloadable_compilers` that I had set up in confix.exs in response to this issue: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/12182

While others might not have my exact issue, looking into your `reloadable_compliers` might be a good thing to explore.